# Github Authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, github, authorization

Are there any ways to use github credentials as an applications authorization? I'm using the github api for a problem and I am trying to figure out how to "log in" with JUST github credentials. Any help and direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try OmniAuth? It's pretty straightforward. https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-github

Answer (score 0):

You can use omniauth-github gem

Also, an example app I built using it (source): https://github.com/jamesy829/oauth-github

Comment: Where do I get the github_key and github_secret from?

Comment: you have to register your application https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/

i am using figaro gem and putting it in the yml file

Answer (score 0):

The Github API supports two types of authentication: **HTTP basic** and **OAuth**.

### Basic Authentication

To use basic authentication, you need to just pass the username and password to the API.

*Example in cURL:*

```
curl -u <username> https://api.github.com/user
```

*Example using [Github API Ruby gem](https://github.com/peter-murach/github)*

```
github = Github.new basic_auth: 'login:password'
```

### OAuth

To use OAuth authentication, you'll need to get an API key. Once you have this, you can use it in place of the username and password.

*Example in CURL*

```
curl -u <token>:x-oauth-basic https://api.github.com/user
```

*Example using [Github API Ruby gem](https://github.com/peter-murach/github)*

```
github = Github.new oauth_token: 'token'
```

#### Obtaining an OAuth token

You can easily generate an API token **for personal and/or testing use** on [this](https://github.com/settings/applications) page under the "Personal access token" section.

**For programatic use or authenticating another user's account**, you'll want to create a new Github application so you can generate OAuth tokens. This can be done on that [same page](https://github.com/settings/applications) page under the "Developer applications" page.

Once you've registered your application, you'll receive a `client_id` and a `client_secret`. You'll need to take those values and use them to authorize a user account and receive a token in exchange.

There are many ways to do this, the easiest being to use the [omniauth-github](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-github) or the [Github API Ruby gem](https://github.com/peter-murach/github#42-application-oauth-access).

Here are some resources to review:

- https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/
- https://github.com/peter-murach/github
- https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-github